# Get the value of a range input slider as a string value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a slider with a label on each end. Is it possible to have the value of the slider to be the text/label?

```
<label for="good">Good</label>
<label for="bad">Bad</label>
<input id="slider" type="range" class="slider" min="1" max="100"/>
```

I know it could be done this way:

```
if(value less than certain amount)
{
   variable = "bad";
}
```

But this would mean I would have multiple statements of this. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', []);

app.controller('demoCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.getText = function(){
    if($scope.slider > 50){
      return "Good";
    } else {
      return "Bad";
    }
  }
});
```

Call this function in interpolation curly brackets in your view:

```
  <span>{{slider}}</span>
  <input ng-model="slider" type="range" min="1" max="100"/>
  <label>{{getText()}}</label>
```

`getText` function will return Bad or Good according to `slider` value.

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/qKzyUjT4fKe0QvT6SYQW?p=preview)**